# Schedule SSRS report for email in HTML format?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, reporting-services, ssis

We have a report (created in `SSRS 2008`) called `DailyBalance.rdl` that can be accessed like so:

> http://OurServer/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fReports%2fDailyBalance&rs:Command=Render

I need to send this report as an email, and the contents of the report needs to be converted to HTML and embedded into the email. That way users that are not in the network can see the contents of the report. It cannot be attachments of links.

This email would then be sent every hour. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I bet you would be interested in [Data Driven Subscriptions in SSRS.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/create-a-data-driven-subscription-ssrs-tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

Report subscriptions are a part of SSRS Report Manager out of the box.

[Subscriptions and Delivery (Reporting Services)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/subscriptions/subscriptions-and-delivery-reporting-services)

When you set up the subscription for a report, make sure to check the *Show report inside message* check box, and use MHTML as the format.

This will put the report results into the body of the email that goes out.